# Change value of jQuery mobile flip switch using php

Tags: php, jquery, selectedvalue, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

Does anyone know how to set the value of a jQuery mobile flip switch using just php?  I have tried the below without any luck.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
<?php 
    ifFilled = '1';
?>

<select name="flip-min" id="flip-min" data-role="slider">
    <option value="1" <?php echo $isFilled == '1' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>Filled</option>
    <option value="0" <?php echo $isFilled == '0' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>Un-Filled</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It looks like it should work.

Comment: Does it work properly if you just hard-code the `selected="selected"` attributes on one of the options?

Comment: For me your code works. Have you checked if `$isFilled` is set correctly to the view? (You could check by `<?php var_dump($isFilled); ?>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opps $ifFilled does not match $isFilled lol  dummy of the year award over here!!!  the code works fine other than that....

Answer (score 0):

Do it with JavaScript:

[Look at this fiddle first.](http://jsfiddle.net/AYLpe/)

```
<label for="flip-a">Select slider:</label>
<select name="slider" id="flipMe" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select> 

<?php if ($ifFilled == true): ?>
var fts = $('#flipMe');
fts.val('on');
fts.slider('refresh');
<?php endif; ?>
```